# Calling Procedure with 'call' function from within P/L SQL Script Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, function, stored-procedures

I am not able to run this simple if/then statement in oracle database. (i think it is 10.x but not sure, seems to be an issue of my sql skill not db version).

Can you help me figure out how to run this simple procedure- email_table_copy() - to send a csv copy of the table only if the table has data in it?

I have to use 'call' with the email_table_copy procedure, and it seems this is where the issue occurs.

I would really appreciate your help.

```
DECLARE
    ncount   NUMBER(10);
    v_sql    LONG;
BEGIN
    SELECT
        COUNT(person_id)
    INTO ncount
    FROM
        test_conditional;

    IF ( ncount > 0 ) THEN
        v_sql := 'call email_table_function(''owner'', ''test_conditional'', ''csv'', ''email@email.com''
);';
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql; 
    END IF;

END;
```

Comment: **Tip of the day:** Do not use LONG data type, use VARCHAR2(32767) or CLOB  if needed. As [Oracle Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF0021) states: **Do not create tables with LONG columns. Use LOB columns (CLOB, NCLOB, BLOB) instead. LONG columns are supported only for backward compatibility.** (emphasis mine) It is a good idea to aviod them in code as well,  they are extremely difficult to work if you ever need to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove `;` from your `v_sql`:

```sql
DECLARE
    ncount   NUMBER(10);
    v_sql    LONG;
BEGIN
    SELECT
        COUNT(person_id)
    INTO ncount
    FROM
        test_conditional;

    IF ( ncount > 0 ) THEN
        v_sql := q'[
           call email_table_function('owner', 'test_conditional', 'csv', 'tyler.hahn@wpr.org')
        ]';
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql; 
    END IF;

END;
```

Also as you can see I've a bit modified your literal to [q-literal](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Literals.html#GUID-1824CBAA-6E16-4921-B2A6-112FB02248DA) to make it more readable.

Simple example:

```sql
begin
  execute immediate q'[
     call dbms_output.put_line('Test string')
  ]';
end;
/
```

Comment: Thank you, Sayan - that fixed it! I am surprised it turned out to be a misplaced semi-colon. And I am grateful to learn of q-literal, that is such a nice operator/tool to have in my toolbox. I'm still new to SQL, and am grateful for your guidance.